# RcppGSL on Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: r, rcpp, autoconf

I'm trying to speed up one of my R programs with Rcpp, which will require me to use several GSL routines. However, I'm having trouble installing RcppGSL on Mac OSX Yosemite (version 10.10.5) and was hoping one of you could help. I've found several questions on SO about installing it on Windows, but none for Mac. I'm an experienced R user, but very new to C++ and Rcpp. I'm not interested in making this into a package - just using it interactively on my machine.

Below, I have a minimal example (I'm calling this file `min_ex.cpp`) There are more GSL headers than what are actually used in the minimal example - these are what I will need in the actual code.

```
#include <RcppGSL.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]
#include <cmath>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_interp.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multiroots.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics_double.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spline.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]] 
NumericVector testFn(int nObs)
{
    Rprintf("Test print");

    RcppGSL::vector<double> Lambda01(nObs);

    return 0;

}
```

This is what happens when I try to use sourceCpp():

```
> library(Rcpp)
> library(RcppGSL)
> sourceCpp('~/Documents/PATH REDACTED/Rcpp/min_ex.cpp')
Error in dyn.load("/private/var/folders/xn/ggql1jjj1t5cbct50ff7yc_h0000gn/T/RtmpTJy2yB/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.15/sourcecpp_35001bd26245/sourceCpp_22.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/xn/ggql1jjj1t5cbct50ff7yc_h0000gn/T/RtmpTJy2yB/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.15/sourcecpp_35001bd26245/sourceCpp_22.so':
  dlopen(/private/var/folders/xn/ggql1jjj1t5cbct50ff7yc_h0000gn/T/RtmpTJy2yB/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.15/sourcecpp_35001bd26245/sourceCpp_22.so, 6): Symbol not found: _gsl_vector_calloc
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/xn/ggql1jjj1t5cbct50ff7yc_h0000gn/T/RtmpTJy2yB/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.15/sourcecpp_35001bd26245/sourceCpp_22.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /private/var/folders/xn/ggql1jjj1t5cbct50ff7yc_h0000gn/T/RtmpTJy2yB/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.15/sourcecpp_35001bd26245/sourceCpp_22.so
```

It seems like the problem may be related to `/Users/MYUSERNAME/.R/Makevars` (which I've never worked with before). These are the current contents of the file:

```
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
```

I also tried adding the following two blocks of text but got the same error:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = $(GSL_CFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(GSL_LIBS)
```

and

```
PKG_LIBS = -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lgfortran
```

My GSL headers are located in `/usr/local/include/gsl`, although "Get Info" displays `/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.4/include/gsl` .

From reading around, it seems like some users have used the `configure.ac` file in the RcppGSL example - would this apply even if I am not creating a package? Just in case, I copied `configure.ac` and `Makevars.in` into the same `Rcpp` directory that contains `min_ex.cpp`, and created the `Rcpp/scr` directory. I installed autoconf with Homebrew and ran `autoconf configure.ac` in Terminal from `~/Documents/PATH REDACTED/Rcpp`. I got more output than makes sense to paste here, but it was not immediately clear whether it worked, except that no Makevars file was produced. How would I correctly run this on my machine? (I think more generally, I don't understand Makevars very well - how would I direct R to use some Makevars file opposed to `/Users/MYUSERNAME/.R/Makevars`?)

Thank you in advance! Please let me know if I can provide any clarifications.

**Edited to add info on my R session:**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RcppGSL_0.3.3     Rcpp_0.12.15      SemiCompRisks_2.7 survival_2.41-3  
[5] MASS_7.3-45      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Matrix_1.2-8    withr_1.0.2     memoise_1.0.0   splines_3.3.2   grid_3.3.2     
[6] digest_0.6.12   devtools_1.12.0 lattice_0.20-34
```

**Edited to add info on using the example package:**
I copied the RcppGSL package over to my working directory, and added the following code to `colNorm.cpp`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]] 
Rcpp::NumericVector testFn(int nObs)
{
    Rprintf("Test print");

    RcppGSL::vector<double> Lambda01(nObs);

    return 0;

}
```

then ran the following in RStudio, which correctly updated `RcppExports.R` and `RcppExports.cpp`.

```
compileAttributes(pkgdir="RcppGSLExample/", verbose=T)
```

In Terminal, I ran:

```
R CMD build RcppGSLExample
R CMD INSTALL RcppGSLExample_0.0.3.tar.gz
```

but when I loaded it into RStudio, I was able to replicate the example with colNorm, but not testFn.

```
> library(RcppGSLExample)
> M <- outer(sin(0:9), rep(1,10), "*") + outer(rep(1, 10), cos(0:9), "*")
> print(colNorm(M))
 [1] 4.314614 3.120504 2.193159 3.261141 2.534157 2.572810 4.204689
 [8] 3.652017 2.085236 3.073134
> testFn(2)
Error: could not find function "testFn"
```

Do you see any steps I may be missing? Thank you!

Comment: You may need to take another pass over the RcppGSL documentation: you need headers _and_ linking, and you use of `sourceCpp()` does not do the latter.  To be honest, I _would_ create a local package.  There is a _working one_ included in the package which you can copy and alter.

Comment: Ie [this example](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppgsl/tree/master/inst/examples/RcppGSLExample) which ships with each copy of RcppGSL.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you for your feedback. I tried your suggestion - if you're able to, could you please take a look at my most recent edits above? Thank you.

Comment: Did you export the function in `NAMESPACE`, or else, does `RcppGSLExample:::testFn(2)` work (using three colons, ie `:::`) ?

Comment: Hi Dirk, this fixed the problem - thank you very much.